# Insert empty row which shows total when Item number get change

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

In my report, there is a table which shows Item number, Employee name, and Hours.

```
Item Number  Employee   Hrs
     1           ABC     2
     1           DEF     1
     2           ABC     3
     2           XYZ     4
```

I want to show one empty row below as a separator when Item number get change. In that row want to show the total number of hours. Like below.

```
Item Number  Employee  Hrs
     1           ABC    2
     1           DEF    1
               Total    3 
     2           ABC    3
     2           XYZ    4
               Total    7
```

Comment: which report you use RDLC,Crystal or HTML??

Comment: I am developing RDLC report

Comment: there is grouping and sum functionality available in RDLC. Please follow this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I don't want to use the grouping. Is there any way to implement this without using group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Bhushan the link was helpful. Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017.
I changed the report design by adding grouping. Also showing sum after each group.